# Acumatica and code128 barcodes not scanning

Tags: barcode, acumatica, barcode-scanner

We are creating barcodes (code128) in Acumatica's Report designer. We have several different types of reports where we have barcodes, and they seem to generally work fine. However, we are seeing issues where certain types of serial numbers aren't able to scan. In fact, for these problem items, the barcodes print out with an "x" over the barcode. I know that is indicative of overlapping components, but in this case, I have removed all of of the components out of the report for testing, and we still see the same issue. I have tries the same number on other reports where it's ok, and we then see the same issue, so I suspect it's something about the number itself (maybe in combination with the barcode settings we have setup). I'm a bit stuck, so hoping that someone has some troubleshooting advice.

Example serial # that works fine: 101230 
Example problem Serial #: FL23432

Could it be the number of characters? the fact that one has letters?

here is a screenshot of the barcode settings as well:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1484s1qtgrpgilk/Screenshot%202019-05-07%2020.40.23.png?dl=0

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

With a value of 10 for property `BarWidth` it displays properly.

[image]

I can reproduce the issue with a `BarWidth` value of 40. I'm pretty sure Acumatica is trying to help you out here. The gaps are too wide for accurate tracking by common lower-end hand scanner. You need to reduce the value of `BarWidth` property until the X disappear.

[image]

**EDIT:**
Actually the red X is just to indicate that the barcode doesn't fit in the control size. You can eliminate it by making the control wider but I'd think that a gap of 40 is still too big for practical scanning in real life scenario:
[image]

Comment: HI, thank you for the update. literally working on this right now. Strangely, my scanner won't scan if the width is less than 40 for some reason. I'm able to get FL123 to scan now, but as i add more numbers it starts to print with an x. If i drop the barwidth it doesn't print with an x, but then it won't scan. I have very limited real estate as i'm printing on a small price label tag and the barcode is already going close to end to end. Any ideas?

Comment: Longer numbers needs more bars to display which makes the bar code longer. So it's the same issue, barcode doesn't fit in control size. As you can see at width 40 it takes more than half the size of letter format.  Any ideas? Refer to the scanner manual to run it's calibration routine so it can scan standard barcodes.

Comment: What you can also try is having a low BarWidth with a higher WidthRatio. Although like with BarWidth you'd want to keep the value reasonably small.

Comment: I have tried many different combinations to no avail. Again, i can get it to print without the x, but i just can't get the barcode scanner to read it then. I read the manual but i'm not really seeing anything in there that is telling...I'm sorry to keep asking for help (and I appreciate the help you have provided thus far), but do you have any other ideas?

Comment: What's the model number and manufacturer of the scanner? Are you able to scan regular barcode with it? ex: will it scan a cereal box?

Comment: At width 40 a regular barcode is about 5 inches wide and I'd expect you'd have to hold the gun half a meter away. It seems like the scanner is uncalibrated if it requires barcode to be that big to register so I'd definitely look deeper into that.

Comment: Nadamoo (Model YHD-5100 to be specific). It can scan normal barcodes.

Comment: The manual can be found here: http://www.yhdaa.com/English/html/1384965148.html

It is barebone but you can reset it to factory defaults. Besides that investigate why it can scan barcode elsewhere. What's the difference between the barcode on the cereal box and the one produced by Acumatica? It should be possible to scan the cereal box to get the number then put the same number in Acumatica report, set the Code type to be similar, print and then compare the outputs. You could even put the cereal barcode directly in standard report image and try to scan that after printed on target paper.

Comment: There's a 1D and 2D variation for YHD-5100 if first link doesn't work, try this one: http://www.yhdaa.com/English/html/1904375018.html

As a last resort I would recommend taking a photo of a known working barcode and embed that photo in the report then scan the printed report. When it's working you can copy the scanned number in a barcode image in the report then change the Code Type until image matches the working barcode.

Comment: Final Update: I continued to play around and was finally able to get a combination that would both print without the X while allowing my barcodes to scan. I changed the barcode height to 400, barwidth to 30 widthratio to 3 and have the sizing to autosize. I also changed the print density to medium (Which actually allows it to scan more consistently. Thank you @HB_ACUMATICA.

Answer (score 0):

To print your labels, try Asgard Labels, the now official Fulfilled By Acumatica solution for label printing. Much easier and it supports all barcodes supported by your printers including 2D.